# How to fail fast a spring boot application for Mongo db related exceptions?

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-mongodb

Basically I want spring boot to terminate if the Mongo DB shows socket exception or authentication error during start up.In My case it continue to run and starts up fine even after the exception. Is there a way to fail it fast and terminate? Also Explain why these errors are handled in spring boot and not thrown up to main thread?

Please don't suggest me to handle it with custom code like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56183731/is-there-way-to-check-correctness-of-mongodb-connection). I want to know is this be done with some configurations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mongo connection related checks runs in the daemon/monitor thread and because of this, the exceptions will never stop the application. Note only exceptions in main thread terminate the program.

To fail fast, embed the connection check logic in bean, so it will throw exception and fail the application at startup.